# Yii-bootstrap Tabs event handler

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I'm using [bootstap tabs](http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/#tbTabs), and Im trying to load the content via ajax rather than set it in PHP. My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function test(e){
       console.log(e.target);
       //load ajax stuff here
   }
</script>


<?php
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs', array(
    'type'=>'tabs',
    'placement'=>'above', // 'above', 'right', 'below' or 'left'
    'tabs'=>array(
        array('label'=>'Ogólne', 'content'=>'Czekaj...', 'active'=>true),
        array('label'=>'Książka adresów', 'content'=>'Czekaj...'),
        array('label'=>'Cośtam', 'content'=>'Czekaj...'),
    ),
    'events'=>array('shown'=>'test')
)); ?>
```

However I keep getting this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Object test has no method 'apply'`. I tried creating an object, but it still didn't work. Any ideas?

A little clarification, JS code created by the framework:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery(function($) {
jQuery('a[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();
jQuery('a[rel="popover"]').popover();
jQuery('#yw0').tab('show');
jQuery('#yw0').on('shown', 'test');
jQuery('#collapse_0').collapse({'parent':false,'toggle':false});
});
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = function(e) {
        console.log(e.target);
        //load ajax stuff here
    }
</script>
```

TbTabs events ( prefixed with 'js:' )

```
<?php
...
'events'=>array('shown'=>'js:test'),
....
?>
```